# Object array is filled with all the same values

Tags: java, arrays, object

i have created a class called BingoCard and i am trying to fill an array of "BingoCard"s with BingoCard dataTypes in a constructor in a new class called BingoGame

```
public BingoGame(int numberOfCards)
{

    bingoCardArray = new BingoCard[numberOfCards];
    BingoCard card = new BingoCard();
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfCards;i++)
    {
        card.fillCard();
        bingoCardArray[i] = card;
    }
//numbers that have been called 
    numbersCalled = new ArrayList<Integer>();

}
```

for some reason it fills the array with the same BingoCard value in each index of the array which is the last value that was entered in the array. For example it fills index 0 with BingoCard of value (A) and at the end of the loop it fills index 5 with BingoCard of value (F) now all indexes of the array contain the value (F). Any ideas why this is happening?
(The card.fillCard() has been tested and works i.e it changes the value of the BingoCard each time)

Comment: You set each to the same card. You need to create a *new* card for each entry.

Comment: the card.fillCard() changes the value of the card though? creating a new card does solve the problem though but i do not understand why

Comment: Because you're changing the value of *the* card, singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the instances inside the loop :

```
for(int i=0;i<numberOfCards;i++)
{
    BingoCard card = new BingoCard();
    card.fillCard();
    bingoCardArray[i] = card;
}
```

If you create just one instance of `BingoCard` before the loop, all the positions in the array would contain the same instance.

Comment: yes thank you this works! If its no trouble could you explain to me the reasoning as to why it was filling it with the same values?

Comment: @Marcus In your code, you are creating ONE object, and then you are adding **the very same** object several times to a list.

Comment: @Marcus You added the same object to the array multiple times. Each time you called `card.fillCard()`, you changed the properties of the same `BingoCard` object, so after the loop all the indices of the array, which contain that same object, will show the latest values that you assigned to this object in the last iteration.